# Is the value in a temporary register preserved if I branch to a label?

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, mips, label, cpu-registers

If the value of $t2 is 1 and the next instruction I execute is:

bne $t2, $0, ELSE

Is the value of 1 that was in $t2 prior to the conditional branch preserved when the branch occurs?

Comment: Temporary registers are only called temporary registers by convention, not because the CPU treats them differently than any other register. No register can change unless some subsequent instruction changes it. That includes the instruction in the branch's delay slot.

Comment: @RossRidge True in general, but MIPS has a special convention that the assembler can use the $at register to synthesize constants and to calculate branch targets, even though they are not mentioned in the code.

Comment: @RossRidge You should post that as an answer.